# Change texture on click cause other objects to hide

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to change the texture of a sphere already created in the scene using a click event. In the scene I have also other elements such as text and collada object.

The code I have changes the texture of the sphere however, it changes the order of the elements in the scene causing the other visible objects to hide behind the sphere. If I change the opacity of the sphere I can clearly see the other elements beyond it.

How can I preserve the order of the elements in the scene when I change the texture?

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);
    var materials = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.left), transparent: true, opacity: 1}), // right
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.right), transparent: true, opacity: 1}), // left
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.top), transparent: true, opacity: 1}), // top
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.bottom), transparent: true, opacity: 1}), // bottom
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.back), transparent: true, opacity: 1}), // back
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.front), transparent: true, opacity: 1})  // front
    ];

    mesh.material = new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials);
});
```

Sphere:

```
var mesh;
var geometry;
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

function init() {
    geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(500, 60, 40);
    geometry.scale(-1, 1, 1);

    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);
    var materials = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.left)}), // right
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.right)}), // left
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.top)}), // top
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.bottom)}), // bottom
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.back)}), // back
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(options.cubic.file.front)})  // front
    ];
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000, 7, 7, 7), new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));
    mesh.scale.x = -1;
    scene.add(mesh);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it could be because of the way how the renderer sorts objects that have  some degree of transparency.

try setting the `renderer.sortObjects = false // default is true ///`

Comment: Yes it was because I had it to true! Also I had to change the transparency to each material to false